# Linking C++ Extensions Without Using raco ctool

Tags: c++, scheme, racket, dynamic-linking

I've successfully built my C++ racket extensions using the raco ctool command line options, but I wanted to remove the dependency on raco because of the way I have my building environment setup. After spending sometime digging through some makefiles on the racket github site, I found that all I need to do to link my extensions correctly is to link against the racket/mzdyn3m.o file. My question is this: should I be linking against the .o file or is there a dynamic library somewhere that I can link against? So basically the link command than I am using looks like this:

`g++ -shared -m64 -Wl $PLT/lib64/racket/mzdyn3m.o -o foo.so foo.o`

Comment: The core Racket devs who are most likely to know the answer to this sort of question, I don't often see here. You might have better luck with it on [the mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html)